# Gnuplot: How to get "time-friendly" hour/min x-axis tick layout

Tags: time, format, gnuplot

I'm having trouble getting a "time friendly" X-axis layout in Gnuplot.

I need to present some data referring to a period within one day; the time X data is represented in decimal form, e.g. X=20.75 meaning 20 hours and 45 mins, the range is generally [0 : 24], but normally a subset, such as [2.25 : 8.75].

The default Gnuplot x-axis layout will be something like the range [0 : 25] with major tics at 0,5,10,15,..., which is nice for normal decimal data, but I would like it to choose something more "time friendly" in the usual clock manner, I mean major ticks at hours 1,2,3 or 6 and minor ticks at 1,5,15 or 30 minutes, suitably chosen depending on the range.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
set xtics 1, 0.25
```

Unfortunately, [according to the manual](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/gnuplot-3.7.1/html_node/gnuplot_152.html#SEC152):

> Minor tics can be used only with uniformly spaced major tics. Since major tics can be placed arbitrarily by `set {x|x2|y|y2|z}tics`, minor tics cannot be used if major tics are explicitly `set`.

Answer (score 1):

Using gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 0
I ended up with this shell script that can be called followed by the desired output name:

save this as makeChart.sh

```html
path='/home/you/yourdir/dat2.txt'

echo "
set terminal unknown
plot '$path' u 1:2
min = (GPVAL_Y_MIN-1)
max = (GPVAL_Y_MAX+1)

set terminal pngcairo size 1400,600 enhanced font 'Helvetica,12'
set timefmt '%H:%M'
set ylabel 'Temperature'
set xlabel 'Time'
unset key
set grid
set title 'Temperature Sensor 1'
set xtics rotate right
set xtics 0,1800,96000
set xdata time
set mxtics 2
set format x '%H:%M'
set format y '%.2f'

set yrange [min:max]

set output '/var/www/somefolder/$1'
plot '$path' u 1:2 index 0  with lines" | gnuplot
```

Some sample data from dat2.txt:
A temperature reading every 5 minutes over one day.

```html
00:05   74.75
00:10   74.85
00:15   74.85
.
.
.
23:30   75.65
23:35   75.65
23:40   75.52
23:45   75.65
23:50   75.65
23:55   75.75
```

run it like this:
you@yourpc $sudo ./makeChart.sh chartx.png

Kept playing with the xtics range until I had 30 minute intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the tics at which gnuplot prints labels with [xtics](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-29800043.89).

An example of placing the xtics would look like this:

```
set xtics (1, 2, 3, 6)
set xtics add 2
set grid
plot [0:24] sqrt(x)
```

The script above will place tics at the positions 1, 2, 3 and 6 and then will repeat the tics at an interval of 2. That will be at 8, 10, 12, ...
`set grid` enables a grid. The documentation can be found [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-19000043.24).

To maybe further improve your plots you might want to check out the time/date data functionalities of gnuplot [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-7700022).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command `set xdata time` to indicate that the X axis data are time values. You can then use something like `set timefmt '%H'` to tell gnuplot how to parse the time values.

For example, to plot the following data with the first column being X values in hours and the second column being the Y axis values:

```
2.25 1
2.50 2
3.00 3
5.25 4
```

Use something like:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt '%H'
plot 'myfile.dat' using 1:2
```

gnuplot should then properly set the x tics to regular time intervals.

Comment: Unfortunately when using '%H' parsing of the first column stops when reaching the decimal separator. You would have to use values like '2:15 2:30 3:00 5:15' in the first column and a time format of '%H:%M'.